# Jmeter fails to connect to a .qvw on an https server

Tags: performance, jmeter, quality-center, why-does-this-fail

I am trying to record a performance test that simulates multiple users logging onto an IP address Access Point.  Each user has a different username/password, and different groups have different section access.  Once logged in and on the Access Point, the user should then be able to access a .qvw application.  When I am connected to the proxy for the recording, I can enter the access point, however the icon of application that I wish to open is a broken image.  Also, when I click on the application link, “The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.”  The tree test results read:

```
Error Count: 1
Response code: 404
Response message: Not Found

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Version: 11.0.11440.0
Set-Cookie: AccessPointSession=7f14b50e-2207-4e5f-be3b-d5862e38288a; path=/; sec
```

I can access the application when not connected to the proxy.

Does anyone have any experience with Jmeter that can help me fix this issue?  I want to be able to record a session within the application. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that no SSL connections are involved here, true? Looks like straight HTTP from your results. SSL issues are the most common cause of failures that only appear when using the proxy.

Comment: One other thing you might check is whether the link to the image and the file are relative or absolute. Absolute links might specify a different port, or protocol,  giving surprising results.

Comment: As per question it looks like 'OP' is facing the issue with HTTPS connection, as he has mentioned the same in the question.

Answer (score 10):

As you have mentioned that when you access the application without a proxy it works fine, but when using via proxy (recording script for JMeter) you are not able to access the application.

From this I understand you are using JMeter's built-in script recorder. Well it does create some problems some times, because some applications don't work well on proxy.

You should try an alternative >> [Blazemter](https://www.register365.com/). Blazemeter has an [extension in Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en-GB). Add this to Google Chrome.

Sign up and login in to the extension.

Now start the script recorder in the extension.

Start browsing your application and URLs in Chrome. The extension will start recording the script along with the required cookies, session and credentials. IT DOESN'T REQUIRE A PROXY CONNECTION FOR THIS.

Once done, stop the recorder and export the test script as `JMX` file. Use this as test plan in **JMeter**!!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the mentioned solution. I can tell you that such issues of opening, accessing files occurs when using Proxy server recording option using JMeter, especially when one is trying it on HTTPS. For such things I have always used [BadBoy](http://www.badboy.com.au/) for recording and creating JMeter script. Download its free version and

1. Navigate to your application using it, while recording is ON
2. Once you have performed all the required actions, stop the recording
3. Save your script as a JMX file, this option is there in the File menu
4. Import this JMX file in JMeter and see if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but I want to share this with the community. I am not sure if you could solve your problem to record a JMeter script, but I want to tell you another way to build a script, because I think is pretty simple.

At my work, we created a simple windows command line which uses [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) sessions to create JMeter scripts. You can find our program [here](https://github.com/hdlopez/ScriptGenerator/tree/master/Binaries%20.NET%204.5). You must record your sessions with Fiddler, pretty straightforward. If you want to improve the organization of the future generated script, mark with a comment every step of your session. For instance, let´s say that you are recording a test case consisting in search something in google. Your first step will be open www.google.com and then, the second one will be type your query in the search box and hit "search in google". To improve the JMeter generation and help the generator to understand your session, select all the request in your Fiddler session corresponding for the first step, and mark them with a comment, for example "step 1". Then, select all the requests corresponding to your second step and mark them as well.

Finally execute the program to create the JMeter script in the following way

```
Abstracta.ScriptGeneratorCLI_4.5.exe -h myapp.com -p 80 -a home -f C:\scripts\yourFiddlerSession1.saz -f C:\scripts\yourFiddlerSession2.saz -o C:\script\outputFolder\
```

The program will create the script and will store it in a file called _AutogeneratedName.jmx located at your output folder (in the example, C:\script\outputFolder).

You can type help for more info

```
-h, --host=VALUE           (required) host name where your web app is
                           hosted. Example: https://myapp.com/home, host =
                           myapp.com
-p, --port=VALUE           port number where your web app is listening.
                           Example: https://myapp.com/home, port = 443
                           This must be an integer. By default the value is

                           80.
-a, --app=VALUE            relative application name. Example:
                           https://myapp.com/home, app = home
-o, --output=VALUE         (required) output path

-f, --fiddlerPath=VALUE    (required) fiddler session path
  --help                 show this message and exit
```

Hope it helps someone